# Hard drive copied itself to another drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have 5 hard drives on my computer.

The first contains a Windows 7 installation
The second and third are drives I use to store data and media.
The fourth is an Ubunut installation
The fifth is an external backup drive

I just finished installing Ubuntu and made an image of the fresh install using Clonezilla

When I was making the clone, I noticed that the second and third drives both had the same name, which normally they don't. After rebooting into Ubuntu, the second and third drives both had the same name and the second drive contained the same contents as the third drive.

In Windows, one of the two drives was offline because of a naming collision, so I changed the id using diskpart, and when I rebooted, both drives are identical.

Most of my stuff was backed up, but not all.

Is there a way to restore the drive?

Comment: It sounds like you used Clonezilla to clone one drive onto the other.